# How to prompt a sweetalert on submit button click php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, sweetalert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Sal.png)I was working on the php laravel framework. I need to prompt a sweet alert showing the terms and conditions on clicking the submit button. I have no clue to use sweet alert. I just used some of the templates and wrote the following code. It's not working. Can anyone help me with this

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('maincontent')
<div class="login-form">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="innerpage-box">
                @include('layouts.errors')
                <div class="innerpage-box-header text-center">
                    <h3></b>Products to Buy</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="register-box-body">
                    <!-- <p class="login-box-msg">REGISTRATION FORM</p> -->
                    <form role="form" id="myForm" action="/chemOrderSave" method="Post" class="bidDetailSave">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{$pro[0]->id}}">
                        <div class="row">
                    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label> <b> Price: </b>
                                    {{$pro[0]->price * 1.02}}
                                </label> </br>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="buyer_quantity"><b> Quantity </b> <star>*</star></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="buyer_quantity" name="buyer_quantity" placeholder="Enter the Quantity" value="{{$pro[0]->quantity}}">
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="chem_shipping">Shipping</label>
                                    <select name="chem_shipping" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option value="">Please select one of the following Shipping Addresses</option>
                                        @foreach($us as $uss)
                                        <option value="{{$uss->id}}" > {{$uss->address}} {{$uss->city}} {{$uss->state}} {{$uss->zipcode}} {{$uss->country}} </option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success updateOrder" ><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Submit</button>
                                <a href="/chemClearDashboard/Buyer/{{$pro[0]->user_id}}" class="btn btn-danger" style="font-size: 1rem !important;"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

In the custom.js I wrote the following code

```
 $('.container').on('click', '.updateOrder', function() {
        //e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var title = "Are you sure, By Clicking accept you agree to Farmerce's user agreement and are agreeing to follow through on this transaction !";
        swal({
            title: title,
            type:'warning',
            showConfirmButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            confirmButtonText:'Confirm',             
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/chemBuyer',
                    data: {'_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(), 'id':id},
                    success: function(data) { 
                        if(data == 'success'){
                            var title= 'Successfully Order Placed!!!';
                            var type='success';
                        }else{
                            var title= 'Some thing went wrong with the '+name+' !!!';
                            var type='error';
                        }
                        swal({
                            title: title,
                            type:type,
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText:'OK',
                        }).then(function(){
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: What is the current behaviour? Any errors? The code looks ok.

Comment: Hey @Hisham, 

So far No errors. I'm expecting to see an alert. But nothing is showing. The form is getting submitted.

Comment: @kirit have you included  custom.js  script in layouts.app.blade.php  ?

Comment: are you not getting the alert either? Where is the js code written? tried doing a hard reload of the page after you added the js code? cleared blade caches?

Comment: hi @JohnLobo

I'm working on the php laravel project. So, it is already linked. Other functions in custom.js are working fine

Comment: @Hisham


I was just dumb. It is working now. All the time I was using Refresh (F5) Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Hisham,


It is working, but there is an issue. I can see the sweet alert, but once I click the submit, I'm seeing the alert and submitting without even me asking to click the confirm or cancel buttons. Can you help me how to fix this?

Comment: Hi @JohnLobo ,

I'm still stuck at the same point. I can see the sweet alert, but it's not letting me click the button. Within a fraction of a second, the form is getting submitted. I want to click either "Confirm or Cancel" before the page is submitted. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: @Kirit better if you provide code snippet or github link

Comment: https://github.com/kirit-pendyala/Computer-Networks/blob/master/Farmerce.mp4

Comment: Please have a look at the above link. I recorded the screen, what's happening

Comment: Make sure you have linked the custom.js file